# Associating a custom post type with a custom (user) taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to create a "team" page template that features several types of information:

- a series a match reports (filtered by the team name- the match
  reports are custom post types with various post meta)
- future matches also filtered by team name (planning on using Simple event attendance
  plugin)
- team logo and header image
- users filtered by team name (user custom taxonomy)

My question is what is the best way to associate the team custom post type with the user meta data of the same name?

For example I have a team named TEAM-A. I want the players from that team to display on the TEAM-A team page.

I am able to create the team page and the user taxonomy page separately but can't seem to associate the two. As it stands, the team name is chosen from a list of teams (custom post types) and saved as metadata.

Here is what I have worked out so far:

```
<?php
$pagename = get_the_title();
$player = get_users($args);
    $args = array(
'meta_key'     => 'tm-name',
'meta_value'   => $pagename,
'meta_compare' => ''
```

); 
    foreach ($player as $user) {
        echo '

' . $user->display_name . '

';
    }
?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$pagename = get_the_title();
$user_query= new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'tm-name', 'meta_value'=>$pagename ));

if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
}
} else {
echo 'No users found.';
}
?>
```